# How to delete session on closing browser?

Tags: session, magento

How do I destroy Magento sessions when a user closes his/her browser in Magento?

I tried to close and reopen my browser and I remain logged in. It looks like Magento persists the login status for certain amount of time. I changed 'cookie lifetime' under configuration, but it does not work.

I could use `session_set_cookie_params()` in index.php, but I would like to know if I can fix it without touching code directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a cookie lifetime of "0" means "when the browser exits". I'm not sure if Magento changes the behaviour but it's worth a try.

Comment: you can set the cookie lifetime form magento backend

Comment: To clarify, setting is at System > Configuration > Advanced / Admin > Security, under 'Session Lifetime'